# Unable to setup Promethues monitored Kubernetes metrics persistent storage on EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I got a kubernetes cluster running on AWS using [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops). I also got prometheus and grafana set up using [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/contrib/kube-prometheus).

What I'm trying to do is to store metrics gathered by prometheus on EBS. My persistent volume claim yaml is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: prometheus-data
  namespace: monitoring

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

And prometheus.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: k8s
  name: k8s
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - name: alertmanager-main
      namespace: monitoring
      port: web
  baseImage: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
  replicas: 2
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
    volumeMounts:
     - name: prometheus-data
       mountPath: "/data"
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      prometheus: k8s
      role: alert-rules
  volumes:
  - name: prometheus-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: prometheus-data
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-k8s
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  serviceMonitorSelector: {}
  version: v2.4.3
```

The 10Gi EBS volume is getting created but it's state remains available. I also tried deleting prometheus pods hoping the data will be retained. Unfortunately that was not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to setup the kube-prometheus with the persistent storage. Please check the following json files:

Promethues-deploy.json

```
{
"apiVersion": "monitoring.coreos.com/v1",
"kind": "Prometheus",
"metadata": {
    "labels": {
        "prometheus": "k8s"
    },
    "name": "k8s-prom",
    "namespace": "monitoring"
},
"spec": {
    "alerting": {
        "alertmanagers": [
            {
                "name": "alertmanager-main",
                "namespace": "monitoring",
                "port": "web"
            }
        ]
    },
    "baseImage": "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus",
    "replicas": 1,
    "resources": {
        "requests": {
            "memory": "400Mi"
        }
    },
    "ruleSelector": {
        "matchLabels": {
            "prometheus": "k8s",
            "role": "alert-rules"
        }
    },
    "securityContext": {
        "fsGroup": 0,
        "runAsNonRoot": false,
        "runAsUser": 0
    },
    "serviceAccountName": "prometheus",
    "serviceMonitorSelector": {
        "matchExpressions": [
            {
                "key": "k8s-app",
                "operator": "Exists"
            }
        ]
    },
    "storage": {
        "class": "",
        "resources": {},
        "selector": {},
        "volumeClaimTemplate": {
            "spec": {
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "storage": "10Gi"
                    }
                },
                "selector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                        "app": "k8s-vol"
                    }
                },
                "storageClassName": "no-provision"
            }
        }
    },
    "version": "v2.2.1"
} }
```

Prometheus-pv.json

```
{
"apiVersion": "v1",
"kind": "PersistentVolume",
"metadata": {
    "labels": {
        "app": "k8s-vol"
    },
    "name": "prometheus-vol",
    "namespace": "monitoring"
},
"spec": {
    "storageClassName": "no-provision",
    "accessModes": [
        "ReadWriteOnce"
    ],
    "capacity": {
        "storage": "10Gi"
    },
    "hostPath": {
        "path": "/data"
    },
    "persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Retain"
},
"status": {
    "phase": "Bound"
} }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok so this is what I did - converted your json to yaml and then ran both of these. A persistent volume was apparrently created by kubectl but couldn't find one on EBS. But, the prometheus pods were not created and I wasn't able to connect to the service.
Question, why did you set storageclass as no-provison? Wait I had to create one too? Sorry Im new to kubernetes.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the serviceaccountname. Now I got a new error - persistentvolumeclaim is not bound

Comment: I got it working! Thanks Prafull. I do however get pvc not bound error when I request for 2 replicas instead 1. Any idea why?

Comment: This is happening because above PV has readwriteonce access mode hence it will allow only one pod to bound to it. So when you provide two replicas of prometheus it need to two PV's to bound to each pod.